# using datepicker('refresh') on ajax success and inline datepicker's beforeShowDay?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using jquery and jquery ui 1.8.7.  I'm creating an inline datepicker when the page loads, then in my ajax success function, I'm calling $('#mydiv').datepicker('refresh'); (I'll post code below).

If the data has been returned from ajax (eg. on the refresh), beforeShowDay calls the highlightDays() function.  I know that I'm hitting highlightDays with the correct data twice before everything crashes to a halt and I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 0 of undefined".

It seems like the events array is being destroyed after a certain amount of time, but I don't know enough about ajax to really say what's happening.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

```
        function highlightDays(date) {
                var day = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
                console.log(typeof(events)); // This will return as an object twice before throwing an the above mentioned error
                if($.inArray(day, events) !== -1) {
                    return new Array(true, '');
                } else {
                    return new Array(false, '');
                }   
        }    
        function getEventData() {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'correct_path', 
                    data: search+'&path='+window.location.pathname,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {        
                        // save our returned data
                        events = new Object();
                        events = data;
                        $('#mydiv').datepicker("refresh");
                    }
                });
            }   

        function createDatepicker() {

            // Attach datepicker to the parent div so it returns as 
            // inline.
            $('#mydiv').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                speed: 'immediate',
                altField: '#edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-1',
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                      if(typeof (_event_days) === 'undefined') {
                        return new Array(true, '');
                      } else {
                            highlightDays(date);
                        }
                    },
            });
            $('#myinput').hide();
        }   
getEventData();
createDatepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what ended up working for me.  Two big differences.  Reworking the highlightDays function and adding all data returned from the ajax call to a global events array, to be used later in highlightDays.

```
var events = [];
function highlightDays(date) {
        var dayClass = [true, ''];
          var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(date));                     
                  $.each(events, function(key, value) { 
                    if (date === value[0])  {
                       dayClass = [true, "ui-state-highlight"];
                       return dayClass;

                    } else {
                        return dayClass;
                    }
                 });
              return dayClass;
          }


        function getEventData() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'myurl', 
                data: search+'&path='+window.location.pathname,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {        
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                       events.push([value]);
                    });
                          // popup is the date input field
                          // attaching datepicker to the parent div makes 
                          // it an inline picker    
                          popup.parent().datepicker('refresh');
                }
            });
        }


        function createDatepicker() {

           popup.parent().datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                 beforeShowDay: highlightDays

            });
            popup.hide();
        }




        function getSearchString() {
            // Return a search string to pass to the ajax call
            var search = window.location.search;
            if(search !== '') {
                while(search.charAt(0) === '?') {
                    // remove the leading question mark in the search string
                    search = search.substr(1);
                }
            }
            return search;
        }

        // If our popup selector exists, create the datepicker and get event data
        if (popup.length) {     
            var search = getSearchString();
            getEventData();
            createDatepicker();
        }
```